# How to view PDFs in Firefox using SumatraPDF

Tags: windows, firefox, sumatra-pdf

I am trying to view a PDF document in my browser (Firefox 3.6 for Windows XP), like the Adobe Reader does, but using Sumatra PDF instead. However, when I try to do this, it comes up in a separate window. Is there any way to make the PDF come up in the browser instead?

Answer (score 3):

Not with Sumatra PDF.

If you want a browser plugin, you could use the light and free *(some advanced features require the not-free Pro version)* [**Foxit Reader**](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/reader3.php).

Comment: SumatraPDF has Firefox plugin since version 1.4

Answer (score 2):

No, and the developers [show no interest in adding this](http://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/issues/detail?id=528).

Comment: It seems a few days ago they commented about that they are going to include a firefox plugin soon in [upcoming sumatra version 1.4](http://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/issues/detail?id=528#c3).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make sure the plugin is installed:

[image: SumatraPDF installer]

Then enable it for PDF files in Content → Applications:

[image: Content -> Applications]